# Failed to validate certificate java.lang.NullPointerException: the keystore parameter must be non-null

Tags: java, keystore, client-certificates

```
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler$X509CertificateValidatorImpl
validate SEVERE: WSS1518: Failed to validate certificate
java.lang.NullPointerException: the keystore parameter must be
non-null at
java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.(PKIXParameters.java:145) at
java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:130)
at
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler$X509CertificateValidatorImpl.validate(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:1646)
at
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.CertificateValidationCallback.getResult(CertificateValidationCallback.java:87)
at
com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.validateCertificate(DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.java:813)
at
com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.CertificateRetriever.setServerCertInTheContext(CertificateRetriever.java:397)
at
com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.initializeOutgoingProcessingContext(SecurityTubeBase.java:641)
at
com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:284)
at
com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:247)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136) at
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050) at
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019) at
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877) at
com.sun.xml.ws.rx.util.FiberExecutor.runSync(FiberExecutor.java:94)
at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.util.Communicator.send(Communicator.java:423) at
com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.runtime.ClientTube.sendSessionControlMessage(ClientTube.java:555)
at
com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.runtime.ClientTube.createSequences(ClientTube.java:415)
at
com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.runtime.ClientTube.openRmSession(ClientTube.java:338)
at
com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.runtime.ClientTube.processRequest(ClientTube.java:179)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136) at
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050) at
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019) at
com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877) at
com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464) at
com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174) at
com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at
com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154) at
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.getAvailableMessageInfo(Unknown Source)
```

Getting this error when i am trying to use the certificates on the Linux box, where in the same certificates work fine on Windows. On Linux I'm using the jdk1.7.0_5 version of java while on windows we are using the jdk1.7.0_03 version. Can this be a possible reason of this error or is some thing else causing this Issue?

Comment: srsly? please format your question and make it more readable for us to give you quality answers

Comment: updated the question , can u please

Comment: Your code would be really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

```
Aug 19, 2014 8:01:09 AM com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler$X509CertificateValidatorImpl validate
SEVERE: WSS1518: Failed to validate certificate
java.lang.NullPointerException: the keystore parameter must be non-null
        at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:145)
        at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:130)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultCallbackHandler$X509CertificateValidatorImpl.validate(DefaultCallbackHandler.java:1646)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.CertificateValidationCallback.getResult(CertificateValidationCallback.java:87)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.impl.misc.DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.validateCertificate(DefaultSecurityEnvironmentImpl.java:813)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.util.CertificateRetriever.setServerCertInTheContext(CertificateRetriever.java:397)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.initializeOutgoingProcessingContext(SecurityTubeBase.java:641)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRequestPacket(SecurityClientTube.java:284)
        at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processRequest(SecurityClientTube.java:247)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.util.FiberExecutor.runSync(FiberExecutor.java:94)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.util.Communicator.send(Communicator.java:423)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.runtime.ClientTube.sendSessionControlMessage(ClientTube.java:555)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.runtime.ClientTube.createSequences(ClientTube.java:415)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.runtime.ClientTube.openRmSession(ClientTube.java:338)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.rx.rm.runtime.ClientTube.processRequest(ClientTube.java:179)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:464)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:174)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.getAvailableMessageInfo(Unknown Source)
        at com.jpmorgan.available.message.DealogicAvailableMessage.getAvailableDealMessageFromDealogic(DealogicAvailableMessage.java:29)
        at com.jpmlink.deal.client.DealogicClient.main(DealogicClient.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

I do get the response back from the web service as the above error ends with ignore the certificate as its not in use

Code

Loading certi

```
 TempKeystoreTO TempKeystoreTO = TempHelper.getKeyStoreProperties();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(TempKeystoreTO.getFileType());
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(TempKeystoreTO.getKeyStoreLocation()),TempKeystoreTO.getCertificatePassword().toCharArray());
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(TempKeystoreTO.getKeyStoreAlias(),new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(TempKeystoreTO.getCertificatePassword().toCharArray()));
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate();
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(TempKeystoreTO.getTrustStoreLocation()),TempKeystoreTO.getCertificatePassword().toCharArray());
    Certificate certificate1 = keyStore.getCertificate(TempKeystoreTO.getTrustStoreAlias());
    ((BindingProvider) ijpmLinkService).getRequestContext().put(XWSSConstants.CERTIFICATE_PROPERTY,certificate);
    ((BindingProvider) ijpmLinkService).getRequestContext().put(XWSSConstants.PRIVATEKEY_PROPERTY,privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey());
    ((BindingProvider) ijpmLinkService).getRequestContext().put(XWSSConstants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, TempKeystoreTO.getCertificatePassword());
    ((BindingProvider) ijpmLinkService).getRequestContext().put(XWSSConstants.SERVER_CERTIFICATE_PROPERTY, certificate1);
    setProperties(TempKeystoreTO.getKeyStoreLocation(), TempKeystoreTO.getTrustStoreLocation(), TempKeystoreTO.getCertificatePassword());

    List<Handler> handlerChain = new java.util.ArrayList<Handler>();
    SOAPHandler handler = null;
    if (service instanceof IJPMLinkService) {
    handler = new DealogicMessageHandler();
    }
    handlerChain.add(handler);
    Binding b = ((BindingProvider) service).getBinding();
    b.setHandlerChain(handlerChain);
```

This works perfectly on windows + Solaris but throws the error on Linux machine